# JavaScript file for building an API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, meteor

I would like to build an API. My application is a meteor/nodejs application. So I created an `api.js` file in the `public` folder:

```
document.write({ example: 'Lorem ipsum' });
```

I would expect to get the object as output by calling `localhost:3000/api.js`, but instead I see the source code.

Second problem:

How do I handle a parameter? e.g. `localhost:3000/api.js?type=article`

```
const type = get[type]; // should be 'article' in this example
```

Using a route will render HTML content, but I need to output plain JSON content...

Comment: In meteor `public` folder is only for serving static assets, which means files are served "as is". It's not meant for creating api or any type of dynamic routes. If you want to build a REST api checkout [this package](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus).

Comment: Do you mean REST api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Meteor works is different, you don't do a document.write, you do things using templates.

In order to provide an api you can use a package such as the Restivus https://atmospherejs.com/nimble/restivus

Which will allow you to create a properly constructed API very easily, and extract URL parameters that you want.

Comment: As far as I can see, it is not possible (with restivus) to get just a port of the collections as response, isn't it? I mean I don't want to send the complete collections to the api, but instead filter the collection to get some of the documents...

Comment: You can expose the complete collection, or you can write a custom handler to do some filtering (eg on the userid)